# Trigger a new build via Codeship API from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, codeship

I have a CI/CD setup with a Jenkins server to manage our internal CI/CD. We have Codeship performing our CI/CD for our AWS work.

I'm looking to setup jobs on our Jenkins server to manage when new builds are triggered on Codeship.

The aim being, we will have our Jira dashboard integrated with Jenkins in such a way that as an issue's status changes, specific jobs are executed.

So I'm trying to create a job that uses [Codeship's API](https://codeship.com/documentation/integrations/api/#builds) to trigger a new build, but it appears that you can only rerun an old build? How do you trigger a fresh build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs [enter link description here](https://codeship.com/documentation/integrations/api/) you can only retrieve information and restart previous builds.

You want to run specific jobs, but those must be associated with some specific commit on your repository. You can identify the build for that specific commit and restart it.

Builds are always triggered from your git repository (github or bitbucket), and Codeship is highly dependent on that to keep the flow as simple as possible. You don't need to upload anything anywhere and then command Codeship to run a build on that. All you need is specify a repository and push something.

You could create an internal git server where your developers push to and with jenkins you can push changes from there to a repository connected to Codeship. That way you could control indirectly what gets tested and what does not.